# Issue centering 2 overlaying images (transparent png)

Tags: html, css

This is my first post and I'm excited to be here with you all.

I'm having an issue centering 2 overlaying png images..

This is what I currently have:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPUET.png)

Now that I have the 2 images located and overlayed how I want them to, how do I center both as if it were one image?

this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Title Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body class="body">
     <div class="top-container">
       <img src="images/goku1.png" alt="goku" class="goku">
       <img src="images/dbzlogo.png" alt="dbz" class="dbzlogo">
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I've tried different codes and methods and while some do work, they only center one of the images.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZV7o.png)

What am I doing wrong? thanks so much!

Comment: Upload your CSS code here, and a link to the images so we can edit it properly

Comment: .body {}

.top-container {


}

.dbzlogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  left: 200px;
}

.goku {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
}

Comment: goku: https://ibb.co/n1cQjss

Comment: dbz logo: https://ibb.co/3R6zrxk

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you want it to look? Do you have an example?

Comment: Heres an example: https://ibb.co/khFNxzh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    html,body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex; 
      align-items: center;
    } 
    
    .dbzlogo {
      width: 70%;
      margin-bottom: 2%;
    }
    
    .goku {
       width: 35%;
       margin-right: -10%;
    }

    .vegeta {
       width: 35%;
       margin-left: -18%;
       margin-bottom: 5%;
       z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">


    <body class="body">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/09MYrjj/goku1.png" alt="goku" class="goku">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cYfLgWx/dbzlogo.png" alt="dbz" class="dbzlogo">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D90PB7G/vegeta1.png" alt="vegeta" class="vegeta">
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hope I helped, if it helped you I'd love for you to mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Awesome! I'ma mess around with the code and see if I can add another character while still maintaining the center

Comment: Ok. I've now added some text and added the additional character. By doing so it has put things out of place. An easy fix would be to just render placements as one image but I would like to learn that by code. Heres whats happened: https://ibb.co/17c5bhD. (link to vegeta png: https://ibb.co/dP8sNQb )

Comment: also the html:  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body class="body">




  <div class="container">


    <center>



      <img src="images/goku1.png" alt="goku" class="goku">

      <img src="images/vegeta1.png" alt="vegeta" class="vegeta">

      <img src="images/dbzlogo.png" alt="dbz" class="dbzlogo">
    </center>







  </div>


  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <p>text</p>



</body>

</html>

Comment: What is your desired outcome?

Comment: Learning how to lock images together in a container/div. That way if I want to move the "group" I can do so by shifting everything together, left, right, top, bottom. My main goal for this is that once I have the 2 characters under the logo I can manipulate it as a group. I've played around and got the placements but if I mess with the window size the character get out of place and theyre not "locked" :(

Comment: I didn't really understand where you want to place the new character? On the right side of the text?

Comment: Are you here? I'm about to go to bed so you better answer me now

Comment: Sorry and yes, on the right side. layered underneath the logo, like the first character.

Comment: I edited the code in my answer, enjoy. If you have any more questions I will read them when I get up

Comment: This is what the placement would look like. https://ibb.co/VvQ0zXG. I know the "blue guy/vegeta" has his eyes covered up, haha but its the philosophy that I want to learn.

Comment: You got it, I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
.body {
  position: relative;
}

.goku {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - xxxpx/2);
}
.dbzlogo {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - yyypx/2);
}
```

xxxpx is pixel of .goku image's height, and yyypx is pixel of .dbzlogo image's width.